# Почему не получается обогнать регулярное выражение?

Tags: php

Регулярное выражение: `/^[a-z\d-]+$/`

Теоретически, без регулярного выражения должно работать быстрее.

```
<?php

// ----------- С РЕГУЛЯРКОЙ -----------
$inp = 'dfghdfghfg';
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000000; $i++) {
    preg_match('/^[a-z\d-]+$/', $inp);
}
echo microtime(true) - $start;
echo '<br>';

// ----------- БЕЗ РЕГУЛЯРКИ -----------
$start = microtime(true);
function f($str) {
    $arr = str_split($str);
    $str2 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-';
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $str2) === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000000; $i++) {
    f($inp);
}
echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

Comment: Не понял вот эту строку `preg_match('/^[a-z\d-]+$/', $inp);` что вы там делаете?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Проверяю `$inp` на соответствие регулярному выражению.

Comment: И как ответ то вот из этой строки получаешь ? `preg_match('/^[a-z\d-]+$/', $inp);`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Никак не получаю.

Comment: https://php.ru/manual/function.preg-match.html

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Мне не нужно получать значение. Я же время измеряю.

Comment: Там и другое можно было прочитать про возвращаемые значения.

Comment: @Hipster, не можете обогнать потому что: 1. в php7 регулярки стали очень быстры; 2. В варианте без регулярки вы дополнительно вызываете пользовательскую функцию, да плюс с ней еще инициализация массива, да плюс цикл!

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan пиши конкретно

Comment: @Alex78191 47 Вот конкретно, и зачем если человек не хочет читать строку в перет, и здесь не прочитает.
`preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет, или FALSE в случае ошибки.`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan вам уже писали выше. `@RazmikGalstyan Мне не нужно получать значение. Я же время измеряю.`

Comment: @Visman 1. Да, в php5 регулярка в 4 раза дольше. Меня эта турбо скорость сбила с толку. 2. Ничего лучше не придумал, всё равно мой вариант медленнее в 4-5 раз.

Comment: без вызова функции и регистрозависимое сравнение на треть быстрее, если что

Comment: @teran Выходит быстрее не написать?

Comment: да может и написать, но проблема в том, что `preg_replace` это вызов скомпилированного кода, а ваши проверки посимвольные это интерпретатор. Второе в итоге заведомо медленнее.

Comment: Эх.. Хотелось сделать быстрее, а получилось только медленнее: https://ideone.com/8XVddU :(

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я тоже через проверку интервалов кодов написал, в 2 раза дольше вышло :D

Comment: вообще, вроде если убрать `str_split` и просто посимвольно брать саму строку, то довольно шустро выходит, даже вроде быстрее регулярок (в 5.6). Формально еще алфавитную-строку можно в порядке убывания частоты встречаемых символов поставить. Но для данного примера не наглядно.

Comment: Потому, что в случае с регуляркой (конкретно вашей), выполняется 1 проход по проверяемой строке, причем скомпилированным кодом функции `preg_match`. В случае без регулярки, у вас интерпретируемый `foreach` плюс на каждую его итерацию проход по шаблону кодом функции `strpos`

Comment: не, что то я наврал про быстрее. накосячил в коде