# Как правильно составить регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть заголовки вида:

```
1. Текст
2. Текст
3.1 Текст
4. Текст
5 Текст
```

Нужно написать регулярку на php которая извлекает отдельно и номер и текст заголовка, при том что число может быть либо float либо int, a точка после числа опциональна.

Пробовал так :

```
/(.*)[\.|] (.*)/s
```

Comment: Можно разбить строку по пробелу, например

Comment: @rjhdby сейчас так и делаю. но хотелось бы более элегантного решения с регуляркой

Comment: регулярка - это не элегантное решение для этой задачи.

Comment: @rjhdby ясно.понятно

Comment: попробовал `/((^|,)((\d)(.\d)(.)|(\d)(.))) (.*)/s` на строке `3.1 Текст` не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна такая регулярка, главное чтобы пробел был, а какое там число не важно.

```
/(.*)\.? (.*)/
```

Для исправления вашего шаблона нужно учитывать, что альтернативы нужно обрамлять обычными скобками, а не квадратными. Опция `single line` по-моему не нужна, ведь в заголовках нет переноса строки.

```
/(.*)(\.|) (.*)/s
```

Если заголовок может содержать пробел, то нужно использовать ленивый квантификатор.

```
/(.*?)\.? (.*)/
```

Comment: точку опциональную после числа не учли. это нужно тогда первую часть проверять на наличие точку вконце и удалять ее через str_replace. Тогда и особо нет смысла в регулярке

Comment: @nullproduction обновил ответ

Comment: все работает. спасибо!

Comment: @nullproduction добавил информацию про ваш паттерн.

Comment: я использую preg_match . там /g выдает ошибку preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: @nullproduction зачем флаг `/s`? В заголовках могут быть переносы строк? В php вместо флага `g` `preg_match_all`, но в вашем случае она не нужна.

Comment: там действительно не нужен модификатор в данном случае

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам пример для любых вариантов (раскомментируйте/закомментируйте любой из вариантов ниже):

```
//$str = 'Текст3';
//$str = 'Текст 3';
//$str = '3Текст';
//$str = '3/5 Текст';
$str = 'Текст 3.7';

preg_match_all('~(\d+)?(?(1)(?:.\d+)?|[^\s\d]+)~', $str, $arr);

echo '<pre>', print_r($arr[0], 1), '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Текст
    [1] => 3.7
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "4.1   sdkjfglhgbkjlfgdf sfghjkghd";
```

1 вариант

```
list($number, $text)= explode(' ', $string, 2);
```

2 вариант

```
$number = strstr($string, ' ', true);
$text = strstr($string, ' ');
```

Надо понимать, что регулярное выражение - это решение для **сложной** обработки **сложной** строки. Они в целом менее наглядны и почти всегда работают медленнее простых строковых функций на простых задачах. Разделение строки по заранее известному разделителю - это очень простая задача.

Comment: У explode() третий параметр есть :Р

Comment: @Visman таки да. Как-то не приходилось им пользоваться, оттого и не помню :)

Comment: Быстро они работают.

Comment: @Alex78191 `быстро` и  `быстрее` - это два разных понятия. Простой посимвольный перебор всегда проще конечного автомата

Answer (score 1):

Ходят слухи, что в php7 регулярки ускорили так, что это ваще омг чит какой-то.

```
(^|\n)(([0-9][\.]?)+)+[\s]+(.+)
```

Здесь из массива $matches Вам нужны будут $matches[2] - номер заголовка, $matches[4] - текст заголовка.

Также полагаю, что раз речь идёт о заголовках, то между ними возможен и текст.
Вариант несколько кривой, но зато работает.

https://regex101.com/r/eKPXdG/1

Comment: Да, я тоже [слышал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728446/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#comment1103105_728446)

Comment: спасибо. это тоже работает. но alex был первым, а два ответа решением я выбрать не могу

Comment: @nullproduction вы можете выбрать ответ, который вам больше подходит.

Comment: @Alex78191 я ваше решение прикрутил уже к коду. все работает. так что пусть будет ваш ответ решением!